# DevExpress FormatString

Tags: devexpress

Im trying to concatenate two different Objects data source with a space between them, like this:

```
FormatString([Check].[CheckAmount] + [Check].[CheckCurrency])
```

How can I add a space between them in the expression editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the `Concat` function:

```
Concat([Prop1], ' ', [Prop2])
```

ps. See the [Criteria Language Syntax](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/DevExpress-Data-Library/Criteria-Language-Syntax) help-article for details.